# Why do operating systems use more RAM for the same processes after you increase the RAM capacity?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, performance

Recently, I increased my RAM capacity from 8 GB to 16 GB and I noticed how both Linux and Windows use more RAM for the *same processes*.

As an example: Before the RAM upgrade I would have Firefox and some other app using say 5 GB of RAM and now if I have *exactly* the same apps running the RAM usage will be much more like around 20%.

I have even passed the 8GB of RAM usage with just a few apps running that before the upgrade would not take more tan 7 GB. Linux and Windows now use much more RAM for everything.

What is the reason of that?

Comment: Not all RAM “usage” is active. Many times that RAM is just reserved for the application just in case and — if something else needs it — the RAM is then freed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is not enough RAM to run all that you wish to run, then the operating system (thinking of Windows here) will use the paging file to fill in for memory.

If you add memory, that is much faster than the paging file on disk and Windows will use the added memory, so then it looks like you are using more memory.

This is normal.  I have ample RAM for my own applications (16 GB) and I do not see any large fluctuation in RAM once apps are loaded into memory.

Other operating systems are similar in nature as to how they deal with memory.

You do not have any hardware issue here.